# Comparing consistency of ratios of two proportions over time

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, distributions, data-visualization, lognormal-distribution

I have two different metrics (supply and demand) distributed over same parameters( Type of occupation). I want to check if the ratio of supply proportion to demand proportion is consistent over time or does it change with time. Which hypothesis test can be used to test this?

**Notes:**

- The Supply distribution is discrete, log-normal with values ranging
  from 390 to 92000.
- The Demand distribution is discrete, log-normal with values ranging
  from 33 to 6700.
- Number of occupations in real data is around 250.

See the image for Example Data
[image]

Here I want to test if the changes in **Ratio** over time are statistically significant.

Comment: Are you looking to do this test for _each_ of your ~250 occupations, based on ~3 data points each? Or some kind of aggregate? In general, you might want to look into [changepoint detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection).

Comment: Thanks for asking this - I need it at aggregate level. Also thanks for suggesting changepoint detection, I am going through it.

Comment: Relatedly: do you actually only have 3 years, or is there more that you just didn't show?

Comment: @Dougal, sorry for delayed response, I have only 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

With only three years for each occupation, I would start out with visualization. Make a lineplot with 250 lines, years along the x-axis. Plotting ratios directly, that will confound levels with slope, but if there are groups of occupations with rather different slopes, that should stand<out in the plot. You could augment the plot with line coloring according to value of an estimated slope.

More formally, you could try some kind of *regression clustering*, see for instance [linear regression inappropriate when there are multiple underlying groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539357/linear-regression-inappropriate-when-there-are-multiple-underlying-groups/539502#539502), but with only three points per line maybe a bayesian variant ...